# Can't change permissions root on folder in AppleScript

Tags: permissions, applescript, privileges

I'm new to AppleScript and I try to make droplet that recursively changes permissions on dropped folder and files within. I wrote this code and it works fine to all items within the root folder but it can't change permissions on the root folder itself. What should I change in this code?

```
property user_name : "suser_root"

property pass_word : "**********"

on open theDroppedItems
    
    repeat with a from 1 to length of theDroppedItems

        set theCurrentDroppedItem to item a of theDroppedItems

        do shell script "sudo chmod -R 777 " & quoted form of POSIX path of theCurrentDroppedItem user name user_name password pass_word with administrator privileges
    end repeat

end open
```

Answer (score 0):

You need HOT FOLDER conception instead of DROPPLET:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property user_name : "suser_root"
property pass_word : "**********"

on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving theDroppedItems
    
    repeat with a from 1 to length of theDroppedItems
        set theCurrentDroppedItem to item a of theDroppedItems
        
        -- make sure dropped item is folder
        if (class of item theCurrentDroppedItem of application "Finder") as text is "folder" then
            
            -- unlock dropped folder and its entire contents
            tell application "Finder" to set entireContents to (entire contents of folder (theCurrentDroppedItem as text)) as alias list
            set end of entireContents to theCurrentDroppedItem
            repeat with anAlias in entireContents
                set theURL to (current application's class "NSURL"'s fileURLWithPath:(POSIX path of anAlias))
                set {theResult, theError} to (theURL's setResourceValue:(false) forKey:(current application's NSURLIsUserImmutableKey) |error|:(reference))
                do shell script "chmod -R 777 " & quoted form of POSIX path of anAlias user name user_name password pass_word
            end repeat
            
        end if
        
    end repeat
    
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: hank you Robert! Your script works great! But I have one problem with using this code: I have the root directory with these weird permissions: sudo stat -f %A /Volumes/snfs1/Files_Exchange/test/TEST_02
700 (all new directories that created by "aspera faspex app" come with this mask "700") and when I try to change permissions on root directory like that I have an error - "You do not have permission to open the document “TEST_02”". I think this error rises on the first line of the script -  on open theDroppedItems and I don't know how to handle this exception...

Comment: Yes Robert, I call "root" directory the hot folder that I want to drop into droplet. The owner of this folder could be one of aspera users, for example user_aspera_01. I can change the mask on that hot folder and it's content with  sudo chmod -R 777 path_to_the_folder but I want to create droplet for automating this process.

Comment: Thank you for replay Robert! I updated code and made the droplet called test06.app but still no luck. When I dropped the folder called "TEST_02" I have the same error- "You do not have permission to open the document “TEST_02”". There is how it looks like https://prnt.sc/15lpkxm

Comment: I updated the answer. Create new folder. On the desktop, for example. Make it HOT folder (other name - folder action) and attach the script above to it.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I created folder named "Change_Permissions_Test_Folder" and attached folder action with code that you posted above. Then I created the folder named "TEST_04" with mask 700 but nothing happened https://prnt.sc/15m4pjm